# Keep Finder location when switching between list view and icon view

Tags: macos, finder

In Finder, if you are at a deep in folders or files while viewing as list mode and then you clicked on icons mode, the Finder shows all folders from the root of volume.  That is very annoying.  Because now you have to go to look for that location again.

See pictures for more details.

How do we keep the Finder to stay at the same location when switching from icons to list mode and vice versa?

[image: Original view]

[image: Unwanted view]

[image: Desired outcome]

Comment: You can make screenshot with cmd-shift-3, but you can make window shot with cmd-shift-4, release all keys, then press spacebar and click to make a photo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are at the same location, namely your root: "Mac1 Sys". You only expanded the folder contents, you did not move into that folder.

It is annoying to others as well ;)
I solve this by <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>mouse-dbl click</kbd> on the folder and move to icon view (<kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>1</kbd>)

In my opinion Finder is old and needs some updating...

Comment: It will work.  Although not as "good user experience" if you know what I meant!

Comment: I do, and therefor some people use alternatives like "XtraFinder", "TotalFinder" and "PathFinder". I think the latter will suite you most. (http://cocoatech.com/pathfinder/). Btw, I have no affiliation with these apps at all.